# (Hot Proxy) watch-storefront compile pixel units to rem

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am using the watch-storefront.
The problem is that the pixel units compile to rem.

[image]

Someone an idea to prevent it for watch-storefront?

Version: 6.4.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this was recently changed](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/5b55fd8f6c726773c6400cef80cebb765349c214#diff-ca7a404fa7e9c58756c9ec8bdfea69ca6cd32a3126be716ef4a3c10b40962f7eL200).

The `postcss.config.js` looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'autoprefixer': {},
        'postcss-pxtorem': {
            propList: ['*']
        }
    }
};
```

So it uses a plugin for `px` to `rem` conversion, but only during hot proxy mode.

If you have to stick with a version of Shopware prior `6.5`, then find the config at `src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/postcss.config.js` or `vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/postcss.config.js`, depending on the template you're using, and simply remove the `postcss-pxtorem` plugin:

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'autoprefixer': {}
    }
};
```

Comment: Damn, I was already in the postcss config but didn't see it.
Thank you very much!